# Can we specialize a template class for a templated class?

Tags: c++, templates

Can we specialize a template class for a templated class?

```
template<>
class Storage8<MyClass<T>>
{
—
—
};
```

Here MyClass is a templated class. Is the above valied? Where do we have to mention
template for MyClass?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
// class templae for Storage8. It can just be a forward declaration
template <typename T> class Storage8;

// or a default defintion.
template <typename T> class Storage8
{
};

// Class templae for MyClass
template <typename T>
class MyClass
{
};

// Specialization of Storage8 for MyClass<T>
template <typename T>
class Storage8<MyClass<T>>
{
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You totally can. Example:

```
#include <vector>
using std::vector;

template<typename T>
struct X {
    static const int A = 0;
};

template<typename U>
struct X<vector<U> > {
    static const int A = 1;
};

int main() {
    static_assert(X<vector<int> >::A == 1, "fail");
    return 0;
}
```